# Error:(25, 28) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'theme' with value '@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar')

Tags: android, xml

could someone explain me this error on android studio?

> Error:(25, 28) No resource found that matches the given name (at
>   'theme' with value '@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar'). Error:(25, 28) No
>   resource found that matches the given name (at 'theme' with value
>   '@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar').

this is my `manifest.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="foo"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="15"
        android:targetSdkVersion="25" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true" >

        <!-- all the activities goes here -->
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

and this is my `styles.xml` file:

```
<resources>

    <style name="FreeWallTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBarTheme</item>

    </style>

    <style name="MyActionBarTheme" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@color/action_bar</item>
        <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/TitleTextStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="TitleTextStyle" parent="android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/action_bar_title</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make this changes in your existing code

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"

        android:supportsRtl="true" >

        <!-- all the activities goes here -->
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
          android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

and Add style

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/btn_background_green</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: just add AppTheme style in style.xml file and replace with your code <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >